# Why is an int* converted to a void**?

Tags: c, pointers, void, void-pointers

I see below code snippet in the open source EDKII code base:

Some context:

```
#define VOID      void
#define SPIN_LOCK_RELEASED          ((UINTN) 1)
#define SPIN_LOCK_ACQUIRED          ((UINTN) 2)
typedef volatile UINTN              SPIN_LOCK;
typedef unsigned __int64    UINTN; //depending on the build options
typedef unsigned __int32    UINTN; //depending on the build options
```

And,

```
BOOLEAN
EFIAPI
AcquireSpinLockOrFail (
  IN OUT  SPIN_LOCK                 *SpinLock
  )
{
  SPIN_LOCK   LockValue;
  VOID        *Result;

  ASSERT (SpinLock != NULL);

  LockValue = *SpinLock;
  ASSERT (LockValue == SPIN_LOCK_ACQUIRED || LockValue == SPIN_LOCK_RELEASED);

  _ReadWriteBarrier ();
  Result = InterlockedCompareExchangePointer (
             (VOID**)SpinLock, // <============= PLACE A
             (VOID*)SPIN_LOCK_RELEASED,
             (VOID*)SPIN_LOCK_ACQUIRED
           );

  _ReadWriteBarrier ();
  return (BOOLEAN) (Result == (VOID*) SPIN_LOCK_RELEASED);
}
```

And the `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer` is implemented as below:

```
VOID *
EFIAPI
InterlockedCompareExchangePointer (
  IN OUT  VOID                      **Value,
  IN      VOID                      *CompareValue,
  IN      VOID                      *ExchangeValue
  )
{
  UINT8  SizeOfValue;

  SizeOfValue = (UINT8) sizeof (*Value); // <=========== PLACE B

  switch (SizeOfValue) {
    case sizeof (UINT32):
      return (VOID*)(UINTN)InterlockedCompareExchange32 (
                             (UINT32*)Value,
                             (UINT32)(UINTN)CompareValue,
                             (UINT32)(UINTN)ExchangeValue
                             );
    case sizeof (UINT64):
      return (VOID*)(UINTN)InterlockedCompareExchange64 (
                             (UINT64*)Value,
                             (UINT64)(UINTN)CompareValue,
                             (UINT64)(UINTN)ExchangeValue
                             );
    default:
      ASSERT (FALSE);
      return NULL;
  }
}
```

AFAIK, it's some logic to handling the different bit width.

For place A, I don't know why we can convert an `UINTN *` into a `void **`. Why explicitly convert a ***pointer*** into a ***pointer-to-pointer***?

For place B, how does it work?

### ADD 1

Inspired by @UnholySheep's comment. If it all boils down to `sizeof(void*)`, why not just write `SizeOfValue = (UINT8) sizeof (void*);` rather than use type conversion on parameter `Value`?

Comment: The second one looks like it's used to determine whether the code is run on a 32bit or 64bit system isn't it? (as that boils down to `sizeof(void*)`)

Comment: Are you asking *why* to know the technical reason, or the logical design reason?

Comment: @StoryTeller I want to know why it is possible to add another level of indirection. I think the level of indirection for pointer conversion should match.

Comment: This code seems to assume that `sizeof(UINTN) == sizeof(VOID*)`, and uses integer to store an address.

Comment: Are you sure it is a pointer to an integer and not just an integer? A pointer to integer cannot get converted to a `void**`.

Comment: Your thinking is correct IMO. I have no idea why this is written in such a way.

Comment: @UnholySheep If it boils down to `sizeof(void*)`, why not just write `SizeOfValue = (UINT8) sizeof (void*);` rather than use parameter type conversion.

Comment: I don't know why - you'd have to ask the author of that code. I wouldn't write code like that (I'd actually try to move that logic into the preprocessor)

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks. I will try to reach the author. Maybe it just works. Or *accidentally* works...

Comment: It's VOID** in uppercase, not the normal void lowecase. How is VOID defined ?

Comment: @Tony `#define VOID      void`

Comment: It would be useful to know also what the type of `UINTN` is, and what is the definition of `SPIN_LOCK_ACQUIRED` and `SPIN_LOCK_RELEASED`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `#define VOID void`? Isn't it just extra complexity for nothing?

Comment: @FabioTurati Thats a literal copy from the original source.